# Reactive Framework cannot convert from 'Project.MainForm' to 'System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler'

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq, system.reactive

**This is code I derived a long time ago from: [ThreadPool Execution Delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38667567/threadpool-execution-delay)**

Im getting the error:
`Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Project.MainForm' to 'System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler'`

From this code:

```
List<Match> Combos = new Regex("^(.{5,}):(.{6,})$", RegexOptions.Multiline).Matches(File.ReadAllText(FileName)).OfType<Match>().ToList();
var query = Combos.ToObservable().SelectMany(s => Observable.Start(() => new {
    source = s,
    grab = checkapache(s.Groups[1].Value, s.Groups[2].Value)
})).Select(x => new {
    x.source,
    x.grab
}).ObserveOn(this).Do(x =>
{
    MessageBox.Show("Test");
});
```

On the line:
`}).ObserveOn(this).Do(x =>`

on `this`.

What it should be doing is Accepting `Project.Form` as the Argument instead of `System.Reactive.Concurrency.IScheduler`

I have tried everything and cannot work out why it's happening.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The error seems fairly self explanatory: `this` is `MainForm` and it doesn't implement `IScheduler`. You most likely want to use one of the built in schedulers, which you can read more about [here](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html#SelectingAScheduler).

Comment: @Enigmativity !Magically, you were the one who gave me this snippet of code back in the day for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38667567/threadpool-execution-delay The exact same reason is why im trying to do the code above but it wont work. Surely since you were the one who worked it out you would be able to help?

Comment: @CharlesMager If you mean to add stuff like ThreadPool andServicePointManager I have both of those added, if not I have no idea what im looking for. That link doesnt personally help me either.

Comment: It looks like that *should* actually work if you're referencing the right bits. You need to install the `System.Reactive.Windows.Forms` package (assuming you're using Rx 3.x).

Comment: @CharlesMager omg thats what did it, Gonna try actually executing Query now.

Comment: Forgot to mention it worked! Thank you a LOT!